# Change the height of the ckeditor text window

Tags: wysiwyg

If I try to change the height and style of the ckeditor text window with css then I find there are numerous layers to the css which makes it difficult to style. Is there a width and height setting in the settings which I can modify?

Comment: Take it you use the WYSIWYG module?

Comment: that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give this a go...

```
/**
 * Set a class on the iframe body element for WYSIWYG editors. 
 * This only works for the WYSIWYG module: http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg
 */
function adaptivetheme_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter(&$settings, &$context) {
  $settings['bodyClass'] = 'wysiwygeditor';
}
```